Pylance crashs in Visual Studio Code on project with large sub-folder
My Pylance suddenly was causing high CPU-usage in VSCode. I was able to use it correctly before, then I wanted to use Jupyter debugging (incl. Run by Line). Suddenly Pylance was using 100% CPU of one core and there were two other processes with 100% utilisation each, both beeing vscode code --utility-sub-type=note.mojom.NoteService
I did restart VSCode but every time it was doing the same thing. At one run I noticed that Pylance crashes after some time with
Pylance has crashed. Would you like to try using a Node.js executable to run the language server?

and
A shared background process terminated unexpectedly. Please restart the application to recover.

The note.mojom.NoteService process continues do to its "CPU-eating" even after the crash.
The project folder does contain a folder with ~1GB of WAV-files. The issue does NOT happen if I only open the jupyter notebook. Also the pylance process continues after the folder is closed in VSCode or VSCode is closed with the folder open (if it did not crash already).
What I tried to resolve it:

Rebooting the device
Switching to Pylance pre-release version

